# How to Search posts using LIKE for Category Name in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

- I need to customize the word press basic search filter.
- It is working fine searching against keywords in post title and post content.
- Now i need to show results where if user enters the name matching the
  category name, then it should pull results from that category as well
  as other results.
- I am assuming, it should be something like using
  LIKE clause for the category_name or category_in operators in tax
  query.

  ```
  $args = get_posts(array(
              'fields' => 'ids',
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
              's' =>  $_REQUEST['s'] ? $_REQUEST['s'] : '' ,
              'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'NAME OF TAXONOMY',
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => 'SLUG OF the TERM', // LIKE (here should be any LIKE clause etc)
                   ),
              )   
          ));
  ```

  How to achieve this scenario, means when user enters any keyword matching the category name it should pull all the results from that category along with general search results.

**Example:** In search bar user writes "**ABC**" and there is category available with name "**ABC Park**", then it should pull results from this category along with results having post titles and content which contain "ABC".

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18715

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/173752

Comment: @AlivetoDie These links are not about searching from category name similar to search term. Also please have a look on edited question. Thanks.

Comment: giving an example how like query need to be added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay... I come up with a solution, I've fetched all category ids from table `terms` with a LIKE query, then in other query passed this array as a category parameter. Here is the code.

```
$term_ids=array(); 
      $cat_Args="SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['s']."%' ";
      $cats = $wpdb->get_results($cat_Args, OBJECT);
      array_push($term_ids,$cats[0]->term_id);    



$q1 = get_posts(array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' =>  $_REQUEST['s'] ? $_REQUEST['s'] : '' 

));
 $q2 = get_posts(array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'category' =>$term_ids
));
$unique = array_unique( array_merge( $q1, $q2 ) );

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => $unique,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
  if ($posts ) : 

foreach( $posts as $post ) :
//show results
endforeach;
endif;
```

But Still i would like a more minimal and precise way. :)

Comment: You can combine the queries by writing some custom SQL that incorporates the get_posts() generated SQL into your first SELECT statement.